# Why can't I connect to a remote private queue of msmq in workgroup windows 8?

Tags: msmq

I am not able to connect to private MSMQ on remote machine.

I have tried many ways like..

1. `MessageQueue rmQ = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=OS:<hostname>\\private$\\<queuename>");`
2. `MessageQueue rmQ = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=TCP:<hostIp>\\private$\\<queuename>");`
3. Also set allowed full control on the queue for everyone and anonynmouse users.
4. Disable firewall.
5. Allowed Nonauthenticated Rpc on both machines.

But not luck. I am getting error Access to Message Queuing system is denied.
I have also observed that assigned "rmQ" object has `MessageQueueException` for all of the properties.

Any help on connecting remote MSMQ will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have MSMQ 5.0 installed on the machine you are sending the message from.

Answer (score 0):

As you get "Access Denied", you must be trying a remote receive over RPC.

[Understanding how MSMQ security blocks RPC traffic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx)